# Access all models produced by rfe in caret

Tags: r, feature-selection, r-caret

I'm using the `rfe` function in the caret package to do feature selection for logistic regression model. I'm looking at `sizes` of 5, 10, 15, 20, and 25 selecting the best model using Rsquared (my dependent variable is 0,1). Is there a way to access the other models produced by the `rfe` function beyond the final selected model?

Comment: Seems like I'm doing something wrong in how I phrase my questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic way. The best thing you can do is to alter the `fit` function and save it yourself. See `rfeControl` and the package vignettes for more details.

Max